# Why does the project yield case class apply/unapply methods compilation error?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In my Play Scala project I would like to insert values into my DB. For this purpose I mapped form fields into `Controller` class but in `Controller` class it showed `apply/unapply` methods are `not a member of object controllers`.

**controllers/User.scala**

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._
import views._
import models._

object User extends Controller {

    val userForm = Form(
    mapping(   
      "username" -> nonEmptyText,
      "emailid" -> text,
      "password" -> nonEmptyText    
      )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
  )


}
```

**models/User.scala**

```
package models

import play.api.db._
import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._
import play.api.Play.current
import scala.language.postfixOps

case class User ( 
  username: String,
  emailid: String,
  password: String

)

object User {


 val simple = { 
    get[String]("user.USER_NAME") ~
    get[String]("user.EMAIL_ID") ~
    get[String]("user.PASSWORD")  map {

      case username~emailid~password => 
        User(username, emailid, password)
    }
  }




}
```

if I run `activator compile` command it shows below `Exception`

```
[error] D:\Test\app\controllers\User.scala:29: value a
pply is not a member of object controllers.User
[error]     )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
[error]            ^
[error] D:\Test\app\controllers\User.scala:29: value u
napply is not a member of object controllers.User
[error]     )(User.apply)(User.unapply)
[error]                        ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 25 s, completed Jun 3, 2015 5:44:05 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because, even though they're in different packages, your controller and your model share the same name, `User`.

You have to disambiguate by specifying the package (e.g. `(models.User.apply)`) as pointed out by Mon Calamari in the comments.

But more importantly, you should rename the controller to `Users` instead to avoid the ambiguity. In the Play Framework, the convention is to pluralize the controller name.